# Saving wrong id for messaging system

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to set up a messaging system on my app and I had it working, but now ActiveRecord is saving the wrong id for the `recipient_id`.

Here's where the `user.id` is loaded as `3` but when the values are inserted the messages's `recipient.id` is `5`:

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "users"."id" 
ASC LIMIT 1
Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" LIMIT 1
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
(0.5ms)  BEGIN

SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "created_at", "recepient_id", "sender_id", 
"subject",   "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "erferfe"],
["created_at", Wed, 17 Dec 2014 19:15:08 UTC +00:00], ["recepient_id", 5], ["sender_id", 3], 
["subject", "erfer"], ["updated_at", Wed, 17 Dec 2014 19:15:08 UTC +00:00]]
(5.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/messages
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

Here's `MessagesController#create`:

```
def create 
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.new(message_params)
  @message.recepient_id = User.find_by(params[:id]).id

  if @message.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Message has been sent.'
    redirect_to messages_path
  else 
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Here's `messages.rb`:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "sender_id"
  belongs_to :recepient, class_name: "User", primary_key: "recepient_id"

  belongs_to :user
```

This is the routing for the messages:

```
resources :users do
  resources :messages
end
```

This is the view:

```
<div class="ui button"><i class="mail icon"></i><%= link_to 'Message', new_user_message_path(@user) %></div>
```

Message_params:

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:subject, :user_id, :content, :recepient_id)
end
```

User.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader


# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter]




TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'change@me'
TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\Achange@me/

attr_accessor :login

has_many :projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "creator_id"

has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"

has_many :recieved_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: 'recepient_id'

has_many :messages

has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy

has_many :authentications, :dependent => :destroy

validates :email, presence: true,
                  uniqueness: true,
                  format: {
                    with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\Z/
                  }

validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update






def downcase_email
 self.email = email.downcase                  
end

def generate_password_reset_token
    update_attribute(:password_reset_token, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(48))
end








def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(:first_name => auth.extra.raw_info.first_name, 
                     :last_name => auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                     :avatar => auth.info.image,  
                     :provider => auth.provider, 
                     :uid => auth.uid,
                     :email => auth.info.email, 
                     :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                    )
    user.confirm!
  end
 user.save
end



def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider 
  user.uid      = auth.uid 
  user.name     = auth.info.name
  user.avatar   = auth.info.image
  user.save
 end



end
```

After code change suggested:

```
User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC  
LIMIT 1
Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "created_at", "sender_id", "subject", "updated_at")  

VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "efvefvf"], ["created_at", Wed, 17 Dec 2014   
21:02:48 UTC +00:00], ["sender_id", 2], ["subject", "erfvef"], ["updated_at", Wed, 17 Dec 2014     
21:02:48 UTC +00:00]]
(7.2ms)  COMMIT
```

Also when I go  /users/:user_id/messages my css and javascript files don't work

Comment: What HTML is being generated by the view? (In particular, what's the URL being generated by `new_user_message_path(@user)`?

Comment: http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/3/messages/new and the form that is generated looks correct

Comment: What are the values in `params` and `message_params`?

Comment: `sender_id` and `recipient_id` are foreign_keys. `belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"`

Comment: Message params are above, and Im passing in the user.id to params is that what your asking? sorry still a bit new

Comment: Changing the primary keys to foreign keys didn't seem to help I also changed the foreign keys to primary keys in the user model and all the messages vanished.

Comment: How is your User model set up?

Comment: Just added it above.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this feature is initialized from a User "Profile" page which allows the current session user (sender) to send a message to the profile user (recipient).

First off, in your Message model, you do not need `belongs_to :user` on the Message model nor do you need `has_many :messages` on the User model.

Next, you have way over complicated the `#create` action:

```
def create 
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.new(message_params)
  @message.recipient_id = params[:user_id]

  if @message.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Message has been sent.'
    redirect_to messages_path
  else 
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Now, adjust your message_params.  You do not need the `user_id` (will be provided by current_user) nor do you need the `recipient_id` (will be provided by the url param).

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:subject, :content)
end
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clean up my code I do appreciate that,but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the log of the Insert that occurred after you updated your code to what I showed you?  Can you also post the url path for the POST action?

Comment: posted log after changes and POST /users/:user_id/messages

Comment: It appears that everything worked but setting the sender (`message_params.merge({recipient_id: params[:id]})` didn't work the way I expected).  See my update.